# Is there an Alchemy system that enables me to make all the potions?

Tags: homebrew, alchemy, dnd-next-playtest

I've been working on making a half-orc mercenary for a D&D Next campaign who used to be a field alchemist for his tribe. However, the way D&D Next is set up makes alchemy very hard. For instance, you need a poisoner's kit to make poisons, a healer's kit to make healing potions, etc. I don't want to spend hundreds of gold to have each kit for each kind of potion, so I decided I would just get one alchemist kit that I can use to make them all.

The real problem came when I realized: I don't know how to make other potions in D&D Next, like the potion of climbing - they haven't made a format for making these other potions.

I would like an easy to use system that allows me to make all of the potions in the D&D Next beta. It would be nice if it included how long it takes for me to gather supplies to make potions and how long it should take to make those potions. I haven't played D&D long so I don't trust myself to make it not over powered or to not make it under powered. It would also be nice if it was in a background format since this is his background.

Comment: Are you asking about how to make potions to boost skills? If you want another alchemy system entirely, you're going to have to be specific about what you want to accomplish with it and what isn't good enough about the current options.

Comment: I don't think going specific would change the answer, because D&D Next states **nothing** about players' magic item creation.

Comment: @Arle I think going specific would help, because they're already asking for something outside of the rules. Providing homebrew rules needs the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably just going to have to wait for the 5e DM's guide to be published this summer.  Until then I would fall back to the alchemy rules given in 3rd edition.